# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' while reading XML

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading XML and adding xml content in dictionary but getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' whenever there are empty tags.

a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="population.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<population>
   <human description="male" product_image="male.jpg">
      <gender sex="Men">
         <id_number>RRX9856</id_number>
         <weight></weight>
      </gender>     
   </human>
</population>
```

Code:
Whenever this code is running, it is throwing mentioned attribute error as there are empty tags i.e x.text() is None.

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict

root_1 = etree.parse('a.xml').getroot()

d1 = []
for node in root_1.findall('.//human '):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
        if x.attrib:
            item[x.attrib.keys()[0]].append(x.attrib.values()[0])
        if x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
    d1.append(dict(item))



d1 = sorted(d1, key = lambda x: x['gender'])
print(d1)
```

Solution I tried:

I am reading above XML and replacing empty value between tags to None by using below code and saving it to some different b.xml. But this is double work where I am reading original a.xml and then replacing empty values with string None and then saving it to b.xml and then reading the new xml file.

```
"%s" % x.text()
```

Is there any other solution which can handle this error in original XML only and there won't be any problem in reading this XML and all the elements including empty values can be also fetched in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to ignore any elements `x` where `x.text` is `None`, then change the line

```py
        if x.text.strip():
```

to

```py
        if x.text and x.text.strip():
```

However, if you want `None` elements to be included but not empty elements (and I have no idea why you would want this) it's probably easiest to replace the lines

```py
        if x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
```

with

```py
        if x is None:
            item[x.tag].append(None)
        elif x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())
```

Comment: I tried this but ignoring is not a solution.  I have to print all the None elements also from XML

Comment: @Enigmaderockz: you are currently ignoring elements with empty (or whitespace-only) text, but you want to include elements where the text is `None`?  Not sure why you would want to do this, but it's easy enough to handle that situation, so I've edited my answer to show how.